# Using bitwise operations on char

Tags: c, binary

So I need some help getting this right. I have an assignment like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char status[1];
} Dish;
```

The variable `status` must only have 1 byte: first 3 bits will contain the number of stars the dish has(0-5), 4th bit tells us if the dish is canceled or not and the 5th bit tells us if the dish is ongoing or not. I tried getting the number of stars like this but it doesn't work:

```
getBit(char data, int bitNumber) {
 return (data & (1 << bitNumber-1)) != 0;
}
int number = 0;
number = getBit(dish.status,0);
number = number << 1 + getBit(dish.status,1);
number = number << 1 + getBit(dish.status,2);
```

Since `status` must only have 1 byte I declared it as above `char status[1]` is it correct?
I also tried using binary operations directly on `status` but it gives me an error saying that I can't use binary operations between a `char` and an `int`. My final objective is getting every information in that byte into a separate variable: `stars`, `canceled`, `ongoing`.

Comment: Did you consider using bit fields instead (https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node13.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field#C_programming_language)?

status[1] creates an array of one element; if you want to make sure it is exactly 8 bits long (why?) you could write char status: 8

Comment: Also bit shifting of negative count is undefined

Comment: I tried using bit fields like u said but it gives me Segfault, the "char status[1]" was the only option without segfault.

Comment: @OscarTheMighty Then you must have done something else wrong in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: I am reading from a binary file and all is good and well before this line of code "fread(cook[i]->dish[j].status,sizeof(char),1,inputFile);"

Comment: You should write `fread(&cook[i].dish, ...)` if `status` isn't an array, also the index variable  `j` does never make sense since the `status` array in your original example has always the length 1, so j must always be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some tweaks your code works:

```
int getBit(char data, size_t bitNumber) {
 return (data & (1 << (bitNumber - 1))) != 0;
}

int main(void) {

  char status = 3 + (1 << 5);

  for (size_t i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
    printf("Bit %d: %d\n", (int) i, getBit(status, i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I used size_t for the bit number (which is unsigned) and fixed the braces around the term.

With bit fields, the code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  union {
    struct {
      unsigned stars:3;
      char cancelled:1;
      char ongoing:1;
    };
    unsigned char data;
  };
} Dish;

void printDish(Dish dish) {
  printf("Stars = %d, Cancelled = %d, Ongoing = %d\nValue: %d\n", dish.stars, dish.cancelled, dish.ongoing, dish.data);
}

int main(void) {

  Dish dish1;
  dish1.stars = 3;
  dish1.cancelled = 1;
  dish1.ongoing = 1;
  printDish(dish1);

  Dish dish2;
  dish2.stars = 5;
  dish2.cancelled = 0;
  dish2.ongoing = 0;

  printDish(dish2);
  return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
 clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
 ./main
Stars = 3, Cancelled = -1, Ongoing = -1
Value: 27
Stars = 5, Cancelled = 0, Ongoing = 0
Value: 37
```

You can access the 'char' value with .data and everything else with named fields. If you want to cast the file you read (via fread), you probably want to make sure alignment of the struct is correct.

See https://repl.it/repls/SimultaneousIncredibleRoot

Answer (score 2):

There is no great sense to declare the data member status as an array with one element

```
char status[1];
```

You could declare it like

```
unsigned char status;
```

The function can look like it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int getBit( unsigned char data, unsigned int bitNumber ) 
{
    bitNumber %= CHAR_BIT;

    return ( data & (1 << bitNumber ) ) != 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i <3; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", getBit( 6, i ) );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0
1
1
```

On the other hand, as the data member `status` consists from bit fields then instead of extracting one bit you could use masks for each bit field to extract it.

Another approach is to use bit fields instead of an object of the type unsigned char. Something like

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char stars: 3;
    unsigned char cancelled: 1;
    //... 
} Dish;
```

Answer (score 1):

As warned about in comments below, kindly note that the behavior of this code is not guaranteed to be consistent across all platforms.
The suggested answers gets the work done. If you don't want to get into bit-shift operations try this:

```
typedef struct dist {
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t number_of_stars : 3 ;
            uint8_t cancel_status : 1 ;
            uint8_t ongoing_status :1 ;
            uint8_t reserved : 3;
        };

        uint8_t status;

    };

} DishType;

DishType Dish;
```

If you check the size of `Dish` you'll see that it still consumes one byte of memory.

You can set the parameters in a single line such as:

```
Dish.status = 0x0C; // For example
```

Or you can set the particular parameter like:

```
Dish.cancel_status = 1;
Dish.ongoing_status = 0;
```

And yet, access or print or modify it individually:

```
printf("\nNo. of starts = %u", Dish.number_of_stars);
```

Comment: Your union declaration is incorrect: you need to put all the bit fields into a struct. By contrast, there’s no need (and no use) to put `status` into an anonymous struct.

Comment: The ordering of bit fields is also completely platform-dependent and unspecified by standard.  There is no guarantee which bits in `status` any of the bit fields actually represent.  Even different compilers on the same system can place the bit fields in a different order and neither would be wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Oh yes, actually it makes sense now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Thanks, I didn't know that. I have used this mechanism to store a lot of status flags in the codes that I have been writing, and fortunately that has never been an issue so far. You are absolutely correct when you say that it platform-dependent (First thing I can think of is endienness). Can you suggest an alternate way which preferably wouldn't require mask operations?